# Problem with scss files affecting more than one view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I'm building a football league web page with ruby on rails. I have three pages(scaffolds) created: news, stats and leaderboard. Each one of them has a scss file and is also affected by `application.scss` and `scaffolds.scss`.

When I change the background color of a table (or anything else) for the stats page to red(just a random color) in `stats.scss`, both the news and leaderboard views are also affected and change their colors to red, even if I had set them to a different color in their own scss files(like blue and green).

I don't understand why this is happening. Isn't the `stats.scss` file supposed to affect only the stats view?

The colors aren't set in the `application.scss` or `scaffolds.scss` files either, so I don't know why every view is being affected by the `stats.scss` file.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use per-page-CSS, but are actually loading all CSS on all pages.

Comment: My advice would be to look at `webpacker`, and configure your views to only load the desired pack(s), rather than always loading everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because rails(or asset pipeline to be precise) will include all your `.scss` files in every page in development environment. Right click on your HTML page -> click "View Page source" and you can see all `.scss` files.

Rails gives you structure of files like `news.scss` or `leaderboard.scss` in `css` folder so that you can organize your controller specific code to make your code life productive. Rails will then bundle and minimize/optimize all of these files in to one file `application.scss` in production environment.

> When I change the background color of a table (or anything else) for the stats page to red(just a random color) in stats.scss, both the news and leaderboard views are also affected and change their colors to red, even if I had set them to a different color in their own scss files(like blue and green).

This is because your `leaderboard` and `news.scss` is loaded first and then `stats.scss` is loaded. Rails asset pipeline will load the CSS files in Ascending order when you use `require tree .` in `application.scss`. Thus, the color values of `leaderboard.scss` and `news.scss` don't apply as `stats.scss` is inluded at the last.

You should consider using different classes or make global background class colors. Ex:

```
// news.scss
.news-table{
  background: "yellow";
}

// stats.scss
.stats-table{
  background: "red";
}
```

Then in your `news.html.erb` file you can use:

```
<table class="news-table">...</table>
```

---

Or you can do this the global way:

```
// application.scss
.red-bg{
  background: red;
}

.yellow-bg{
  background: yellow;
}
```

Then in your `news.html.erb` and `stats.scss` files:

```
// news.html.erb
<table class="red-bg">...</table>

// stats.html.erb
<table class="yellow-bg">...</table>
```