# SCSS files in Ruby on Rails app affecting all HTML.erb views

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I am working on different HTML.erb files for different pages of an app, but it seems like the SCSS files for css affect all of my HTML.erb files, even when I call the scss file in only one of the html.erb. Is this how it is supposed to be, or any advice over putting ids for everything?
Like for my frontpage.html.erb,  I have a SCSS file called frontpage.scss.
When I put

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'frontpage', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

in my scss, it also changes that case for all my other html.erb files.

This might be a simple question, but I would really appreciate some advice, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question was asked here:  [Problem with scss files affecting more than one view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493347/problem-with-scss-files-affecting-more-than-one-view)

Unfortunately, this is simply how rails works. The link to the question/answer I provided should adequately explain how it works and how to approach the issue.